# Select fechando ao clicar em todos os IE's

Tags: css

Estou tendo um problema, que em todas as versões do Internet Explorer, ao clicar em um select, ele fecha automaticamente ao mover o cursor, sem a possibilidade de escolher um dos OPTIONS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   <form action="/pesquisar" name="formpesqf" method="POST" class="form-search form-private">
        <div class="input text">
            <label for="text">Nome do produto ou referência</label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield" id="text" class="f field-top" title="Nome do produto ou referência" placeholder="Nome do produto ou referência" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="buton" value="Pesquisar" class="btn-search fleft transition" />
        <div class="input select">
            <label for="grupo">Buscar por grupo:</label>
            <select name="grupo" class="sel-header" onChange="submit();">
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <!-- BEGIN BLOCK_SESSAO_FLUTUANTE -->
                <option value="{value_ses}" {SELECTED_GRUPO}>{text_ses}</option>
                <!-- END BLOCK_SESSAO_FLUTUANTE -->
            </select>
        </div>
      <div class="input select">
           <label for="marca">Buscar por marca:</label>
           <select name="marca" id="marca" class="sel-header" onChange="submit();">
               <option value="">Selecione</option>
               <!-- BEGIN BLOCK_MARCA_FLUTUANTE -->
               <option value="{value_mc}" {SELECTED_MARCA}>{text_mc}</option>
               <!-- END BLOCK_MARCA_FLUTUANTE -->
           </select>
      </div>
   </form>

.sel-header {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 170px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.form-private .f,
.form-private .sel-header {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #999999;
}
.form-private .btn-search,
.sel-header,
.form-private .f {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
}
.form-private .f:hover {
    height: 26px;
    width: 327px;
}
.form-private .f:hover,
.form-private .sel-header:hover {
    border: 2px solid #62A639;
}
```

Comment: Desculpa mas.. quê? o.O

Comment: Eu tenho o select acima, clico para expandir as opções, e ao tentar escolher alguma, o select simplesmente, fecha sozinho o.O

Comment: Isso cheira a evento de `hover` ou `mouseenter` sendo (mal)tratado via Javascript.

Comment: Isso, IE = Internet Explorer, no caso, com base no HTML acima, ambos os dois selects estão com este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hover dos selects, estava efetuando o seguinte:

```
.form-private .f:hover {
    height: 26px;
    width: 327px;
}
.form-private .f:hover,
.form-private .sel-header:hover {
    border: 2px solid #62A639;
}
```

Somente removi os :hovers, e foi corrigido o problema. :D

Comment: Ué, mas não tinha `:hover` nenhum no CSS que você postou na pergunta!

Comment: Não havia publicado esta parte do código, pois não sabia que tinha algo a ver com este problema, vou atualizar a pergunta.